# In python, how to extract indices of elements of a vector which are present in a subset vector

Tags: python, vector, subset, indices

I have a vector of integers (no repetitions, each value appears once).
I then have a second, shorter vector, which is a subset of the first.
Is there a "pythonic" way (with no 'for loops') to extract the array of indices that give the positions in the first vector, of the elements of the second (subset) vector?

Comment: "for cycles" means `for` loop?

Comment: `list(map(v.index, s))`

Comment: Using numpy: `np.where(np.isin(vector, sub_vector))[0].tolist()` (note: tolist only needed if want result as Python list rather than Numpy array).